# How to use User Points for storing Quiz scores?

Tags: userpoints

How can I add points directly to the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) database? I have a quiz site and would like to use the [User Points](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) module to store quiz scores, instead of creating something from scratch. I have created a taxonomy "Quiz" for such points.

Every quiz ends by showing the score made (between 0 to 100 depending on how many answers they got right). I would like to go on and store this in the userpoint database.

I am using the following code but I'm getting 2 error messages:

> Notice: Undefined variable: user in ...
>   Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ....

The code I am using is the following one:

```
$params = array (
  'uid' => $user->uid,
  'description' => 'Totals points from quizes',
  'points' => $percentage,
  'tid' =>127,
);

userpoints_userpointsapi($params);
```

Answer (score 3):

[Userpoints](http://drupal.org/project/userpoints) has an [API](http://drupal.org/node/206558).

See especially `userpoints_userpointsapi()` Something like this: `userpoints_userpointsapi(array('uid'=>$some_user, 'points'=>9000));`

You might also be interested in the [Quiz](http://drupal.org/node/507090#12) module which supports Userpoints.

Comment: Thanks. I found the following code which is working fine except am getting the following 2 errors. (I editted main code to include this errors + code.

Comment: Well, looks like you have no defined $user object, you need to define the uid who should receive the points *somehow*.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the [7.x-5.x version](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/7.x-5.0-rc3) of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you can take advantage of the integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module that this new [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) release comes with (which was not in the 7.x-4.x version version), which doesn't require any custom code at all.

To do so, have a look at the [delivered rule](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/quiz.rules_defaults.inc#n18), which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_send_results_at_the_end_of_a_quiz" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send quiz results at the end of a quiz",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "quiz" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "quiz_result_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result-unchanged:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:uid:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: Your results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:uid:name],\r\n\r\nYou finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nYour score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz-results\/[quiz-result:result-id]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:nid:author:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: [quiz-result:uid:name]\u0027s results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:nid:author:name],\r\n\r\n[quiz-result:uid:name] finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nTheir score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz\/results\/[quiz-result:result-id]\/view",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (and Rules UI, a submodule of it), just clone the above rule (using the Rules UI) and replace both Rules Actions with a Rules Action to grant an amount of User Points that is equal to `[quiz-result:score]` (note that this token is also shown in the Rules example above (within the Rules Action).

If you're not familiar with how to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to grant user points, then have a look at the answer to "[How to grant userpoints only for modifying nodes last changed at least 20 days ago?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159360/how-to-grant-userpoints-only-for-modifying-nodes-last-changed-at-least-20-days-a/213335#213335)" (which also includes a Rules example to make that happen).