# How to grant userpoints only for modifying nodes last changed at least 20 days ago?

Tags: 7, nodes, rules, userpoints

I am not sure how to go about this. I use the [Userpoints](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module in Drupal 7 to attribute points to users who create nodes ('reviews'). I also want to allow them to gain some points if they supersede or modify an existing node... but only if the previous creation/mod was done over 20 days before.

How can I do this with [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules)? Or else, how should I code it manually?

Comment: I will have a look at it in the next week. A bit short on time at the moment (the dreaded deadline...). Thanks for your answer anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to say, but the previous answer has some challenges:

- Rules Event `After saving new content` is not the right event.
- I disagree with the "*You will need a custom module ...*", since there is an out-of-the-Rules-box Rules Condition you can use ... Read on for more details on that.

Here is a rule (in [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) Export format) that does what you're asking for:

```
{ "rules_grant_userpoints_after_updating_old_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Grant userpoints after updating old content",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "node-unchanged:changed" ],
          "op" : "\u003C",
          "value" : "-20 days"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "points" : "123",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Modify existing node (nid=[node:nid]) that was not updated in the last 20 days.",
          "operation" : "Grant points",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "site:current-user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "total_points" : "Number of points in all categories together" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You now have [total-points:value] points" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

Some more details about the above rule:

- Rules Event: After updating existing content (you may want to limit it to selected content types only).
- Rules Condition: Token `[node-unchanged:changed]` is at least from 20 days ago.
- Rules Actions:

  - Grant `123` user points (adapt the number and the other options as you want).
  - Load the current userpoints balance.
  - Display a message with the current userpoints balance.

If you have the Rules UI enabled (and the [Userpoints Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints_rules) module, you should be able to just import the above rule in your own site.

PS: After you're convinced the rule works as you want, you may want to remove the last 2 Rules Actions about the message shown to the user after user points were granted.

Comment: This worked as well. It is a good non-code alternative. Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 0):

## Giving points for adding new Review nodes:

1. Create new Rule; event: `After saving new content` + restrict by type: `Review`.
2. Action: `Grant points to a user`.

Note: you need to have `Userpoints rules integration` installed.

---

## Giving points for updating Review nodes after certain period of time

You will need a custom module where you will create a new rule Condition using [`hook_rules_condition_info()`](http://www.drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!rules!rules.api.php/function/hook_rules_condition_info/7).
This condition will check if previous node revision is older than XX days (in your case 20 days).

Here's an example:

```
function YOUR_MODULE_rules_condition_info() {
  return array(
    'YOUR_MODULE_condition_compare_revision' => array(
      'label' => t('Compare date of last revision'),
      'parameter' => array(
        'node' => array(
          'label' => t('Node'),
          'type' => 'node',
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}

function YOUR_MODULE_condition_compare_revision($node) {
  $revision = db_select('node_revision', 'r')
    ->fields('r', array('nid'))
    ->condition('nid', $node->nid)
    // Make sure this is not the last revision.
    ->condition('vid', $node->vid, '!=')
    // Make sure this revision is older than your desired period of time.
    ->condition('timestamp', REQUEST_TIME - 20 * 24 * 60 * 60, '<=')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchObject();

  return $revision;
}
```

This could would go to `YOUR_MODULE.rules.inc`.

*Note*: I wrote this quickly and without testing. Should be working fine though.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. This was critical in achieving my goal. I do however want to make a correction. Since I want the user to get points only if the 'previous' update is older than a certain date, I actually needed to make sure that there were no reviews between the date of the latest review and 20 days before. I therefore used:
->condition('timestamp', array(REQUEST_TIME - 15 * 24 * 60 * 60, REQUEST_TIME), 'BETWEEN')
    ->execute()
    ->fetchAll();

Comment: Glad it was useful. If it solved your problem, accept the answer as a solution. It will help others with similar problem in the future, comments can get deleted.