# How can I add points for selected answers to questions implemented using Polls?

Tags: polls

The users of my page have to answer a test, which I'm making with the Polls module.

I have a custom currency called "points". The users points have to grow when they answer the test correctly, in order to buy things in the store with [Drupal Commerce](https://www.drupal.org/project/commerce).

I really don't know how to do this, any suggestions?

Comment: It's not quite clear. Is there a right answer and a wrong answer and users should get the points only if they have the right answer, or your goal is to encourage user engagement and they'll get the point(s) anyway as long as they participate in your poll ?
Which version of drupal are you running ?
You might want to try userpoints if you're using D7

Comment: 1.Users only get the point if they have the right answer. 2.I'm running drupal 7,52 3. I have installed userpoints and userpoints commerce but I don't know how to connect it to polls

Answer (score 0):

By using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module, and some extra work, you can get this to work, as detailed below ...

#### Step 1: Use Rules to grant User Points

Use Rules to create a custom rule with a Rules Action that grants points (using the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module). Have a look at the rules exammple included in my answer to "[How to grant userpoints only for modifying nodes last changed at least 20 days ago?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/159360/39516)", especially the very first Rules Action in it. Here is how that Rule looks like:

```
{ "rules_grant_userpoints_after_updating_old_content" : {
    "LABEL" : "Grant userpoints after updating old content",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "userpoints_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "node_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : {
          "data" : [ "node-unchanged:changed" ],
          "op" : "\u003C",
          "value" : "-20 days"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "userpoints_action_grant_points" : {
          "user" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "points" : "123",
          "tid" : "0",
          "entity" : [ "" ],
          "description" : "Modify existing node (nid=[node:nid]) that was not updated in the last 20 days.",
          "operation" : "Grant points",
          "display" : "1",
          "moderate" : "default"
        }
      },
      { "userpoints_rules_get_current_points" : {
          "USING" : { "user" : [ "site:current-user" ], "tid" : "all" },
          "PROVIDE" : { "loaded_points" : { "total_points" : "Number of points in all categories together" } }
        }
      },
      { "drupal_message" : { "message" : "You now have [total-points:value] points" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

The 2nd and 3rd Rules Action is rather to facilitate testing (you may want to ignore those Actions after QA-testing).

#### Step 2: Make (core) Poll trigger the Rule

To continue with the Rule from Step 1, you don't want to use that ***Rules Condition*** there, so just delete that. However the crucial part for your case is to have an appropriate ***Rules Event*** to replace the event used in the Rule from Step 1. In your case you want to use a Rules Event like "***When user casts a vote***".

Guess what, there seems to be a (sandbox) module that provides exactly that Rules Event: the [Poll Rules Integration](https://www.drupal.org/sandbox/topsitemakers/2065931). If you don't want to use a sandbox project, then just look at this project to see what's needed for that event to build your own custom module to create such event.

#### Step 3: Further complete your Poll-puzzle

After you complete Step 1 and 2 above, the only thing left to complete your "puzzle", is to implement an appropriate Rules Condition to check "*if they answer the test correctly*" (as in your question, for which you did not specify any further details).