# How to grant User Points after Quiz questions are answered correctly?

Tags: 7, rules, userpoints, quiz

I have the [User Points](https://www.drupal.org/project/userpoints) module enabled and I want to use the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module to create a rule which lets a user win User Points whenever the user answers correctly my questions.

I don't know what should I put as Rules Event and as a Rules Condition.

How can I specify that the user only earns User Points when the answer is correct?

Comment: Please provide more details on how you've built the Quiz in Drupal that will define which Rule event/condition will fit in your case.

Comment: Have you tried Quiz userpoints(https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz_userpoints) module?

Answer (score 2):

## If using Quiz 7.x-5.x

Assuming you're using the [7.x-5.x-rc3 version](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/7.x-5.0-rc3) of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you can take advantage of integration with the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module that this new release comes with.

To do so, have a look at the [delivered rule](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/quiz/tree/quiz.rules_defaults.inc#n18), which looks like so:

```
{ "rules_send_results_at_the_end_of_a_quiz" : {
    "LABEL" : "Send quiz results at the end of a quiz",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "ACTIVE" : false,
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "TAGS" : [ "quiz" ],
    "REQUIRES" : [ "rules", "entity" ],
    "ON" : { "quiz_result_update" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result-unchanged:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "0" } },
      { "data_is" : { "data" : [ "quiz-result:is-evaluated" ], "value" : "1" } }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:uid:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: Your results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:uid:name],\r\n\r\nYou finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nYour score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz-results\/[quiz-result:result-id]",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      },
      { "mail" : {
          "to" : [ "quiz-result:nid:author:mail" ],
          "subject" : "[site:name]: [quiz-result:uid:name]\u0027s results for [quiz-result:nid:title]",
          "message" : "[quiz-result:nid:author:name],\r\n\r\n[quiz-result:uid:name] finished the quiz [quiz-result:nid:title] on [quiz-result:time-start]\r\n\r\nTheir score: [quiz-result:score]%\r\n\r\nYou can access the result here: [site:url]node\/[quiz-result:nid:nid]\/quiz\/results\/[quiz-result:result-id]\/view",
          "language" : [ "" ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

After you enable [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) (and Rules UI, a submodule of it), just clone the above rule (using the Rules UI) and replace both Rules Actions with a Rules Action to grant an amount of User Points that you may want to be related to `[quiz-result:score]` (note that this token is also shown in the Rules example above (within the Rules Action).

If you're not familiar with how to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) to grant user points, then have a look at the answer to "[How to grant userpoints only for modifying nodes last changed at least 20 days ago?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/159360/how-to-grant-userpoints-only-for-modifying-nodes-last-changed-at-least-20-days-a/213335#213335)" (which also includes a Rules example to make that happen).

## If using Quiz 7.x-4.x

For the [7.x-4.x version](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz/releases/7.x-4.0-rc2) of the [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module, you may want to try the [patch](https://www.drupal.org/files/quiz_rules_integration.patch) from [fago](https://www.drupal.org/u/fago) (aka the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) maestro ...), attached to [issue # 1300420](https://www.drupal.org/node/1300420), which has a description like so (note the last phrase in it ...):

> ... adds basic rules integration to quiz. It includes an event when users have finished taking a quiz, a condition to check whether a user has passed a certain quiz and an action to clear quiz results for a user.
>
> Patch works for me.